# Is there another way to make a parent DIV to accommodate floating elements without `overflow: hidden` style on it?

Tags: html, css, css-float, overflow, css-position

Long story short, I've a bunch of floating elements within a div `#top` and to accommodate the proper positioning of the floating elements, it has `overflow: hidden` applied to it.

I need to position some of elements within this div relative to it however when I do, they won't get displayed outside of div because it has overflow hidden.

Here's basic HTML structure that I've:

```
<div id="top" style="height: 50px; position: relative">
 <div id="clickme1">
  <div id="big-div" style="position: absolute; height: 500px; width: 800px; display: none">
    lots of content
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="clickme2">
   ...
 </div>
</div>
```

`#clickme1` and `#clickme2` have `float: left`.

`#top` has `overflow: hidden`.

Now when user clicks `#clickme1` it makes `#big-div` visible. However because `#top` has 50px height, but `#big-div` has 500px height, I only see 50px from the `#big-div`.

Any ideas how to make `#top` still position correctly but not use `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: Just use some javascript to resize `#top` depending wether `#big-div` is visible or not

Comment: @Ahmad Top has to always stay 50px! What I need is to have `#big-div` to somehow still positioned relative to Top, but also overflow it.

Comment: Well, makes that when user click on `#clickme1` position of `top` becomes `absolute` so there won't be overflow hidden